# jinja2 template inheritance sample does not work

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates, jinja2

Anybody successful on trying jinja2 template inheritance? The sample just work partially for me.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    <div id="footer">
        {% block footer %}
        &copy; Copyright 2008 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

index.html (child template)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
      Welcome on my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

My output

[image]

My problem: 
1. page title is "Index". It should be "Index - Mypage"
2. No footer

Please help!!!!
For reference: I am using most updated google app engine, python 2.7, IDE is Visual studio 2012 + Python for Visual Studio, [KAY framework](http://kay-docs.shehas.net/tutorial.html) (extended from django and jinja2)

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('myapp/index.html')
```

Comment: Can you show the render step in Python code?

Comment: Hello, I just modified my question based on the sample taken from jinja2 documment since nobody answered my previous question. Could you please help? Thanks!!!

Comment: Still no Python code. This is even more relevant since you're using another framework.

Comment: Python code is added. But nothing special in python code.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Do you maybe have two versions of base.html lying around? I know jinja will look in multiple template directories (if so defined) and pick the first one it finds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jinja2 follows inheritance from your TEMPLATE_DIRS settings. I'm assuming that you have an incorrect path. Try:

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}
```

Comment: you are right. I just wonder why??? I put base.html and index.html in the same folder. why do I need myapp/base.html